# Resetting graph in Tensorflow 2

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

In my use case, I have some time series data where at each time `t`, I train a new model over a rolling window. In tensorflow 1, I had to do the following otherwise models will accumulate in the default graph and essentially leak memory.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend as K
...
tf.reset_default_graph()
K.clear_session()
```

In tensorflow 2, I've found equivalent functions [tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/reset_default_graph) and [tf.keras.backend.clear_session()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/clear_session). However, from the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate), TF2 ties graph variables to python variables so theoretically if a python variable is destroyed, the graph variable should also be destroyed. Is this interpretation correct? I've tried putting model creation code in a loop, whilst memory usage still grows, it wasn't the sort of explosion I've witnessed in TF1.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63411142/how-to-avoid-oom-errors-in-repeated-training-and-prediction-in-tensorflow